# In which cases someone can edit a question and answer in Stack Overflow & How point distributed?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

Suppose I asked a question.

There may some grammatical mistake.

But someone edits and fixed the silly grammatical mistake.

Is there any issue will arise if I don't accept the edit.

If I accept the edit. Then how the point will be distributed per upvote?

One extra thing I need to know, the tag. There is thousand tag that can match with a question, somehow I missed one. And someone add a tag make it edit. Can I prevent this?

Comment: Voting to migrate to Meta SE

Comment: sorry i don't got your answer

Comment: "There is thousand tag that can match with a question, somehow I missed one. And someone add a tag make it edit. Can I prevent this?" -- If the tag fits the question, why would you want to prevent it?

Comment: You don't miss out on any reputation points if someone edits your post, if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any issue will arise if I don't accept the edit.

Not inherently, but if grammatical mistakes are left alone then other people will edit them. If all the edit does is fix grammatical mistakes, why would you not want it?

> If I accept the edit. Then how the point will be distributed per upvote?

The post remains yours, and you will still get all the points from it.

> And someone add a tag make it edit. Can I prevent this?

No, you cannot prevent this. I don't think you should *want* to prevent this, as the correct tags can be important to getting your question answered.

Stack Exchange is built around high quality questions. People with over 2000 reputation can edit posts freely, and will edit any that can be improved. If someone writes posts that require improvement to fit our standards, but refuse to improve it themselves and refuse to even let other people improve it for them, the community is not as likely to be helpful.